# magento 2 override pricing for configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, catalog-price-rules, configurable-price

> I need to override magento 2 pricing for configurable product. Can you please let me know which is the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried with plugin or preference method ?

Comment: Yes @zedBlackbeard I have tried plugin method. It is working fine without catalog price rule and i need it to work with catalog price rule.